# UICollectionView - Find out current index path and change values/data

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to figure out how I can capture the current index path of my collection view.

I am using a horizontal-flow, and I have already stated the following:

```
  func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
```

There are three pre-defined cells, and I wish to change the text/UI elements on each of the three collection view cells, accordingly. How can I achieve this? I'm really struggling, as currently I am getting 3 cells full of the same data. Which is expected.

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

               let cell = detailsCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DetailsCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DetailsCollectionViewCell
                cell.layer.shadowRadius = 1
                cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
                cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.5, height: 5)

                return cell
        }
    }
}
```

But in essence I wish to  do the following, pseudo code:

```
    if cell.indexPath == 0 {
      label.text = "This is the first cell"

    } else if cell.indexPath == 1 {
     label.text = "This is the second cell"

    } else if cell.indexPath == 2 {
     label.text = "This is the third cell"
   }
}
```

Apologises if this is a stupid question.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: In your pseudo code, write it in `collectionView(_ collectionView:cellForItemAt:)` and replace `if cell.indexPath == 0 ` with `indexPath.row == 0` (and so on).

Comment: @Larme In a `UICollectionView`, you should use `item` instead of `row` to find out the number of an item.

Comment: I'm struggling, what do I call before `collectionView(_ collectionView:cellForItemAt:)`? Stupid question, I know.

Comment: As I keep getting this error `Cannot call value of non-function type 'UICollectionView'` @Larme

Comment: Actually, I am an idiot. I just realised what you mean. I apologise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare the `item` property of the `indexPath` parameter of `cellForItemAt`.

```
if indexPath.item == 0 {
    //first item
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'd accept the answer, but low rep, sadly. But, once again, thank you so much kind sir! Edit - I must wait for another minute. Then I shall accept. Thank you, again.

Comment: @SwiftLearner You welcome. You can accept this answer in a minute or so, it's a matter of a time limit, not the lack of reputation.

Comment: Yes, I figure haha! Thank you again. And I have accepted your answer.